# how to make eclipse recognize emulator and reload app every run

Tags: android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
 You must restart adb and Eclipse.
 squares_senior_project] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Users\Nick\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.

I have been continually getting the above error when I try to run my application for the past 4 days now.  I can start the emulator through the AVDM and run an older version of my app that has already been loaded, but for some reason the emulator wont update the app anymore and I cant figure out why.  When I try to run it once the emulator is up and running I get the error: createRenderThread failed to connect.  I have restarted my computer, eclipse, and the adb.  I thought it may have been something with my firewall keeping the computer from recognizing the emulator but I cant see any thing that seems to be related to eclipse, I could be wrong though.  This is my senior project and the dead line is approaching and i'm getting desperate so any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.